# Error while publishing AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

We are trying to publish AWS Lambda function using .NET Core Web application and got the following error message

[image]

Comment: are you trying to create an S3 bucket somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set your parameters during the publishing.

Open serverless.template file in your project. In "Parameters" section find out 'ShoudCreateBucket' and 'BucketName' items. Then you have to set/add 'Default' value of these items.

Also, you could set these parameters during deployment (click 'Next' instead of 'Publish' on the first deployment screen).

Check out more details in this tutorial [Tutorial: Build and Test a Serverless Application with AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-build-test-severless-app.html).